# Local Storage with Expiration

Tags: javascript, cookies, local-storage, session-storage

How can I set an expiration time on a specific local storage variable?

Example:
If I have a page disclaimer and once the user clicks "accept" I store a certain variable in the local storage. However after 12 hours, I want it to get deleted and ask the user to accept again.

I don't want to store the variable in session storage, because the disclaimer will prompt every time the user opens a new tab.

Cookies would be another solution, but I rather not use it if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: There's no built-in way to expire values in local storage. The solution is to store a date value as well and check that on the next visit.

Comment: Could you give me more information on how to store a date value and check it on the next visit? (An example if possible) Thanks! @Aaron

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's no built-in way to expire values in storage. One solution is to store a timestamp, then in each visit compare the stored time (if there is one) against the local time to determine if the value has expired. Example:

```
const expirationDuration = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 12; // 12 hours

const prevAccepted = localStorage.getItem("accepted");
const currentTime = new Date().getTime();

const notAccepted = prevAccepted == undefined;
const prevAcceptedExpired = prevAccepted != undefined && currentTime - prevAccepted > expirationDuration;
if (notAccepted || prevAcceptedExpired) {
  alert("Disclaimer: ...");
  localStorage.setItem("accepted", currentTime);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend the usage of [lscache](https://github.com/pamelafox/lscache). Just include this 2.5kb JS into your APP or per CDN. Its highly configurable and usage its pretty easy. It supports strings or objects.

```
If (lscache.get('myVar') === null) {
  alert('time exceeded')
  //set variable which will expire in 3 days
  lscache.set('myVar', true, (60*24*3))
}
```